# Logging to Database using Custom Logger Provider in Blazor Server

Tags: database, logging, blazor, iloggerfactory

I'd like to log any `Ilogger` data into database in `Blazor Server`. So according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmFsQJBbsO0) I created [this repository](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorCustomILoggerProviderToSendLogToDataBase).

When I run the project, the first page of the project is displayed for a while, but it closes suddenly. As far as I understand, the problem is from recording too much information in the database in the [following section](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorCustomILoggerProviderToSendLogToDataBase/blob/master/Util/DatabaseLogger.cs) in a short time. Because when the following code is commented in [log method](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorCustomILoggerProviderToSendLogToDataBase/blob/master/Util/DatabaseLogger.cs), the problem is solved. How do I fix this problem?

```
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You should create a ConcurrentQueue for it. I have a sample of it here: https://github.com/VahidN/DNTIdentity/blob/master/src/ASPNETCoreIdentitySample.Services/Identity/Logger/DbLoggerProvider.cs#L18

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my question. Would you like  to present it in the form of an answer?